# How can I objdump the assembler code of dynamically linked functions in a dynamically linked executable?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, objdump

Compiling a minimal C++ program:
`g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -o prog main.cpp`

```
int main()
{
}
```

---

Performing an `objdump -C -D prog` of all sections I am given the following output:

```
prog:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .interp:

0000000000400200 <.interp>:
  400200:   2f                      (bad)  
  400201:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  400202:   69 62 36 34 2f 6c 64    imul   $0x646c2f34,0x36(%rdx),%esp
  400209:   2d 6c 69 6e 75          sub    $0x756e696c,%eax
  40020e:   78 2d                   js     40023d <_init-0x193>
  400210:   78 38                   js     40024a <_init-0x186>
  400212:   36 2d 36 34 2e 73       ss sub $0x732e3436,%eax
  400218:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  400219:   2e 32 00                xor    %cs:(%rax),%al

Disassembly of section .note.ABI-tag:

000000000040021c <.note.ABI-tag>:
  40021c:   04 00                   add    $0x0,%al
  40021e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400220:   10 00                   adc    %al,(%rax)
  400222:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400224:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
  400226:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400228:   47                      rex.RXB
  400229:   4e 55                   rex.WRX push %rbp
  40022b:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40022d:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40022f:   00 02                   add    %al,(%rdx)
  400231:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400233:   00 06                   add    %al,(%rsi)
  400235:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400237:   00 20                   add    %ah,(%rax)
  400239:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    ...

Disassembly of section .hash:

0000000000400240 <.hash>:
  400240:   03 00                   add    (%rax),%eax
  400242:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400244:   05 00 00 00 01          add    $0x1000000,%eax
  400249:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40024b:   00 04 00                add    %al,(%rax,%rax,1)
    ...
  40025e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400260:   02 00                   add    (%rax),%al
  400262:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400264:   03 00                   add    (%rax),%eax
    ...

Disassembly of section .dynsym:

0000000000400268 <.dynsym>:
    ...
  400280:   10 00                   adc    %al,(%rax)
  400282:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400284:   20 00                   and    %al,(%rax)
    ...
  400296:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400298:   77 00                   ja     40029a <_init-0x136>
  40029a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40029c:   12 00                   adc    (%rax),%al
    ...
  4002ae:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4002b0:   1f                      (bad)  
  4002b1:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4002b3:   00 20                   add    %ah,(%rax)
    ...
  4002c5:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4002c7:   00 3b                   add    %bh,(%rbx)
  4002c9:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4002cb:   00 20                   add    %ah,(%rax)
    ...

Disassembly of section .dynstr:

00000000004002e0 <.dynstr>:
  4002e0:   00 6c 69 62             add    %ch,0x62(%rcx,%rbp,2)
  4002e4:   73 74                   jae    40035a <_init-0x76>
  4002e6:   64 63 2b                movslq %fs:(%rbx),%ebp
  4002e9:   2b 2e                   sub    (%rsi),%ebp
  4002eb:   73 6f                   jae    40035c <_init-0x74>
  4002ed:   2e 36 00 5f 5f          cs add %bl,%ss:0x5f(%rdi)
  4002f2:   67 6d                   insl   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
  4002f4:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  4002f5:   6e                      outsb  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  4002f6:   5f                      pop    %rdi
  4002f7:   73 74                   jae    40036d <_init-0x63>
  4002f9:   61                      (bad)  
  4002fa:   72 74                   jb     400370 <_init-0x60>
  4002fc:   5f                      pop    %rdi
  4002fd:   5f                      pop    %rdi
  4002fe:   00 5f 49                add    %bl,0x49(%rdi)
  400301:   54                      push   %rsp
  400302:   4d 5f                   rex.WRB pop %r15
  400304:   64 65 72 65             fs gs jb 40036d <_init-0x63>
  400308:   67 69 73 74 65 72 54    imul   $0x4d547265,0x74(%ebx),%esi
  40030f:   4d 
  400310:   43 6c                   rex.XB insb (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  400312:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  400313:   6e                      outsb  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  400314:   65 54                   gs push %rsp
  400316:   61                      (bad)  
  400317:   62                      (bad)  
  400318:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  400319:   65 00 5f 49             add    %bl,%gs:0x49(%rdi)
  40031d:   54                      push   %rsp
  40031e:   4d 5f                   rex.WRB pop %r15
  400320:   72 65                   jb     400387 <_init-0x49>
  400322:   67 69 73 74 65 72 54    imul   $0x4d547265,0x74(%ebx),%esi
  400329:   4d 
  40032a:   43 6c                   rex.XB insb (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  40032c:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  40032d:   6e                      outsb  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  40032e:   65 54                   gs push %rsp
  400330:   61                      (bad)  
  400331:   62                      (bad)  
  400332:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  400333:   65 00 6c 69 62          add    %ch,%gs:0x62(%rcx,%rbp,2)
  400338:   6d                      insl   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  400339:   2e 73 6f                jae,pn 4003ab <_init-0x25>
  40033c:   2e 36 00 6c 69 62       cs add %ch,%ss:0x62(%rcx,%rbp,2)
  400342:   67 63 63 5f             movslq 0x5f(%ebx),%esp
  400346:   73 2e                   jae    400376 <_init-0x5a>
  400348:   73 6f                   jae    4003b9 <_init-0x17>
  40034a:   2e 31 00                xor    %eax,%cs:(%rax)
  40034d:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  40034e:   69 62 63 2e 73 6f 2e    imul   $0x2e6f732e,0x63(%rdx),%esp
  400355:   36 00 5f 5f             add    %bl,%ss:0x5f(%rdi)
  400359:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  40035a:   69 62 63 5f 73 74 61    imul   $0x6174735f,0x63(%rdx),%esp
  400361:   72 74                   jb     4003d7 <_init+0x7>
  400363:   5f                      pop    %rdi
  400364:   6d                      insl   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  400365:   61                      (bad)  
  400366:   69 6e 00 47 4c 49 42    imul   $0x42494c47,0x0(%rsi),%ebp
  40036d:   43 5f                   rex.XB pop %r15
  40036f:   32 2e                   xor    (%rsi),%ch
  400371:   32 2e                   xor    (%rsi),%ch
  400373:   35                      .byte 0x35
    ...

Disassembly of section .gnu.version:

0000000000400376 <.gnu.version>:
  400376:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400378:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40037a:   02 00                   add    (%rax),%al
  40037c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    ...

Disassembly of section .gnu.version_r:

0000000000400380 <.gnu.version_r>:
  400380:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
  400382:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
  400384:   6d                      insl   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  400385:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  400387:   00 10                   add    %dl,(%rax)
  400389:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40038b:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40038d:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40038f:   00 75 1a                add    %dh,0x1a(%rbp)
  400392:   69 09 00 00 02 00       imul   $0x20000,(%rcx),%ecx
  400398:   89 00                   mov    %eax,(%rax)
  40039a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  40039c:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
    ...

Disassembly of section .rela.dyn:

00000000004003a0 <.rela.dyn>:
  4003a0:   d0 08                   rorb   (%rax)
  4003a2:   60                      (bad)  
  4003a3:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4003a5:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4003a7:   00 06                   add    %al,(%rsi)
  4003a9:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4003ab:   00 01                   add    %al,(%rcx)
    ...

Disassembly of section .rela.plt:

00000000004003b8 <.rela.plt>:
  4003b8:   f0 08 60 00             lock or %ah,0x0(%rax)
  4003bc:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4003be:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4003c0:   07                      (bad)  
  4003c1:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
  4003c3:   00 02                   add    %al,(%rdx)
    ...

Disassembly of section .init:

00000000004003d0 <_init>:
  4003d0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4003d4:   48 8b 05 f5 04 20 00    mov    0x2004f5(%rip),%rax        # 6008d0 <_DYNAMIC+0x200>
  4003db:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  4003de:   74 05                   je     4003e5 <_init+0x15>
  4003e0:   e8 2b 00 00 00          callq  400410 <__libc_start_main@plt+0x10>
  4003e5:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  4003e9:   c3                      retq   

Disassembly of section .plt:

00000000004003f0 <__libc_start_main@plt-0x10>:
  4003f0:   ff 35 ea 04 20 00       pushq  0x2004ea(%rip)        # 6008e0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
  4003f6:   ff 25 ec 04 20 00       jmpq   *0x2004ec(%rip)        # 6008e8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
  4003fc:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000400400 <__libc_start_main@plt>:
  400400:   ff 25 ea 04 20 00       jmpq   *0x2004ea(%rip)        # 6008f0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x18>
  400406:   68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
  40040b:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   4003f0 <_init+0x20>

Disassembly of section .plt.got:

0000000000400410 <.plt.got>:
  400410:   ff 25 ba 04 20 00       jmpq   *0x2004ba(%rip)        # 6008d0 <_DYNAMIC+0x200>
  400416:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400420 <_start>:
  400420:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  400422:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  400425:   5e                      pop    %rsi
  400426:   48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  400429:   48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  40042d:   50                      push   %rax
  40042e:   54                      push   %rsp
  40042f:   49 c7 c0 80 05 40 00    mov    $0x400580,%r8
  400436:   48 c7 c1 10 05 40 00    mov    $0x400510,%rcx
  40043d:   48 c7 c7 f7 04 40 00    mov    $0x4004f7,%rdi
  400444:   e8 b7 ff ff ff          callq  400400 <__libc_start_main@plt>
  400449:   f4                      hlt    
  40044a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000400450 <deregister_tm_clones>:
  400450:   55                      push   %rbp
  400451:   b8 08 09 60 00          mov    $0x600908,%eax
  400456:   48 3d 08 09 60 00       cmp    $0x600908,%rax
  40045c:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40045f:   74 17                   je     400478 <deregister_tm_clones+0x28>
  400461:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400466:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  400469:   74 0d                   je     400478 <deregister_tm_clones+0x28>
  40046b:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  40046c:   bf 08 09 60 00          mov    $0x600908,%edi
  400471:   ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
  400473:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400478:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400479:   c3                      retq   
  40047a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000400480 <register_tm_clones>:
  400480:   be 08 09 60 00          mov    $0x600908,%esi
  400485:   55                      push   %rbp
  400486:   48 81 ee 08 09 60 00    sub    $0x600908,%rsi
  40048d:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400490:   48 c1 fe 03             sar    $0x3,%rsi
  400494:   48 89 f0                mov    %rsi,%rax
  400497:   48 c1 e8 3f             shr    $0x3f,%rax
  40049b:   48 01 c6                add    %rax,%rsi
  40049e:   48 d1 fe                sar    %rsi
  4004a1:   74 15                   je     4004b8 <register_tm_clones+0x38>
  4004a3:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4004a8:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  4004ab:   74 0b                   je     4004b8 <register_tm_clones+0x38>
  4004ad:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004ae:   bf 08 09 60 00          mov    $0x600908,%edi
  4004b3:   ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
  4004b5:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
  4004b8:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004b9:   c3                      retq   
  4004ba:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

00000000004004c0 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
  4004c0:   80 3d 41 04 20 00 00    cmpb   $0x0,0x200441(%rip)        # 600908 <__TMC_END__>
  4004c7:   75 17                   jne    4004e0 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x20>
  4004c9:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004ca:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004cd:   e8 7e ff ff ff          callq  400450 <deregister_tm_clones>
  4004d2:   c6 05 2f 04 20 00 01    movb   $0x1,0x20042f(%rip)        # 600908 <__TMC_END__>
  4004d9:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004da:   c3                      retq   
  4004db:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4004e0:   f3 c3                   repz retq 
  4004e2:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
  4004e6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4004ed:   00 00 00 

00000000004004f0 <frame_dummy>:
  4004f0:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004f1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004f4:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004f5:   eb 89                   jmp    400480 <register_tm_clones>

00000000004004f7 <main>:
  4004f7:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004f8:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004fb:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400500:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400501:   c3                      retq   
  400502:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400509:   00 00 00 
  40050c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

    ...

  (Due to limits of the body in SO questions I'm cutting it off here)
```

---

But as I'm single stepping through the debugger, I eventually end up in the assembler code of `__libc_start_main` (whose code is not seen in the objdump of the program):

```
0x00007ffffe790740 <__libc_start_main+0>:   push   %r14
0x00007ffffe790742 <__libc_start_main+2>:   push   %r13
0x00007ffffe790744 <__libc_start_main+4>:   push   %r12
0x00007ffffe790746 <__libc_start_main+6>:   push   %rbp
0x00007ffffe790747 <__libc_start_main+7>:   mov    %rcx,%rbp
0x00007ffffe79074a <__libc_start_main+10>:  push   %rbx
0x00007ffffe79074b <__libc_start_main+11>:  sub    $0x90,%rsp
0x00007ffffe790752 <__libc_start_main+18>:  mov    0x3a37ef(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ffffeb33f48
0x00007ffffe790759 <__libc_start_main+25>:  mov    %rdi,0x18(%rsp)
0x00007ffffe79075e <__libc_start_main+30>:  mov    %esi,0x14(%rsp)
0x00007ffffe790762 <__libc_start_main+34>:  mov    %rdx,0x8(%rsp)
0x00007ffffe790767 <__libc_start_main+39>:  test   %rax,%rax
0x00007ffffe79076a <__libc_start_main+42>:  je     0x7ffffe790837 <__libc_start_main+247>
0x00007ffffe790770 <__libc_start_main+48>:  mov    (%rax),%eax
0x00007ffffe790772 <__libc_start_main+50>:  xor    %edx,%edx
0x00007ffffe790774 <__libc_start_main+52>:  test   %eax,%eax
0x00007ffffe790776 <__libc_start_main+54>:  sete   %dl
0x00007ffffe790779 <__libc_start_main+57>:  lea    0x3a3900(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ffffeb34080 <__libc_multiple_libcs>
0x00007ffffe790780 <__libc_start_main+64>:  test   %r9,%r9
0x00007ffffe790783 <__libc_start_main+67>:  mov    %edx,(%rax)
0x00007ffffe790785 <__libc_start_main+69>:  je     0x7ffffe790793 <__libc_start_main+83>
0x00007ffffe790787 <__libc_start_main+71>:  xor    %edx,%edx
0x00007ffffe790789 <__libc_start_main+73>:  xor    %esi,%esi
0x00007ffffe79078b <__libc_start_main+75>:  mov    %r9,%rdi
0x00007ffffe79078e <__libc_start_main+78>:  callq  0x7ffffe7aa280 <__GI___cxa_atexit>
0x00007ffffe790793 <__libc_start_main+83>:  mov    0x3a36d6(%rip),%rdx        # 0x7ffffeb33e70
0x00007ffffe79079a <__libc_start_main+90>:  mov    (%rdx),%ebx
0x00007ffffe79079c <__libc_start_main+92>:  and    $0x2,%ebx
0x00007ffffe79079f <__libc_start_main+95>:  jne    0x7ffffe790876 <__libc_start_main+310>
0x00007ffffe7907a5 <__libc_start_main+101>: test   %rbp,%rbp
0x00007ffffe7907a8 <__libc_start_main+104>: je     0x7ffffe7907bf <__libc_start_main+127>
0x00007ffffe7907aa <__libc_start_main+106>: mov    0x3a3707(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ffffeb33eb8
0x00007ffffe7907b1 <__libc_start_main+113>: mov    0x8(%rsp),%rsi
0x00007ffffe7907b6 <__libc_start_main+118>: mov    0x14(%rsp),%edi
0x00007ffffe7907ba <__libc_start_main+122>: mov    (%rax),%rdx
0x00007ffffe7907bd <__libc_start_main+125>: callq  *%rbp
0x00007ffffe7907bf <__libc_start_main+127>: mov    0x3a36aa(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ffffeb33e70
0x00007ffffe7907c6 <__libc_start_main+134>: mov    0x170(%rax),%r14d
0x00007ffffe7907cd <__libc_start_main+141>: test   %r14d,%r14d
0x00007ffffe7907d0 <__libc_start_main+144>: jne    0x7ffffe7908cb <__libc_start_main+395>
0x00007ffffe7907d6 <__libc_start_main+150>: test   %ebx,%ebx
0x00007ffffe7907d8 <__libc_start_main+152>: jne    0x7ffffe7908a8 <__libc_start_main+360>
0x00007ffffe7907de <__libc_start_main+158>: lea    0x20(%rsp),%rdi
0x00007ffffe7907e3 <__libc_start_main+163>: callq  0x7ffffe7a5250 <_setjmp>
0x00007ffffe7907e8 <__libc_start_main+168>: test   %eax,%eax
0x00007ffffe7907ea <__libc_start_main+170>: jne    0x7ffffe79083e <__libc_start_main+254>
0x00007ffffe7907ec <__libc_start_main+172>: mov    %fs:0x300,%rax
0x00007ffffe7907f5 <__libc_start_main+181>: mov    %rax,0x68(%rsp)
0x00007ffffe7907fa <__libc_start_main+186>: mov    %fs:0x2f8,%rax
0x00007ffffe790803 <__libc_start_main+195>: mov    %rax,0x70(%rsp)
0x00007ffffe790808 <__libc_start_main+200>: lea    0x20(%rsp),%rax
0x00007ffffe79080d <__libc_start_main+205>: mov    %rax,%fs:0x300
0x00007ffffe790816 <__libc_start_main+214>: mov    0x3a369b(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ffffeb33eb8
0x00007ffffe79081d <__libc_start_main+221>: mov    0x8(%rsp),%rsi
0x00007ffffe790822 <__libc_start_main+226>: mov    0x14(%rsp),%edi
0x00007ffffe790826 <__libc_start_main+230>: mov    (%rax),%rdx
0x00007ffffe790829 <__libc_start_main+233>: mov    0x18(%rsp),%rax
0x00007ffffe79082e <__libc_start_main+238>: callq  *%rax
0x00007ffffe790830 <__libc_start_main+240>: mov    %eax,%edi
0x00007ffffe790832 <__libc_start_main+242>: callq  0x7ffffe7aa030 <__GI_exit>
0x00007ffffe790837 <__libc_start_main+247>: xor    %edx,%edx
0x00007ffffe790839 <__libc_start_main+249>: jmpq   0x7ffffe790779 <__libc_start_main+57>
0x00007ffffe79083e <__libc_start_main+254>: mov    0x3a8ecb(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ffffeb39710 <__libc_pthread_functions+400>
0x00007ffffe790845 <__libc_start_main+261>: ror    $0x11,%rax
0x00007ffffe790849 <__libc_start_main+265>: xor    %fs:0x30,%rax
0x00007ffffe790852 <__libc_start_main+274>: callq  *%rax
0x00007ffffe790854 <__libc_start_main+276>: mov    0x3a8ea5(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ffffeb39700 <__libc_pthread_functions+384>
0x00007ffffe79085b <__libc_start_main+283>: ror    $0x11,%rax
0x00007ffffe79085f <__libc_start_main+287>: xor    %fs:0x30,%rax
0x00007ffffe790868 <__libc_start_main+296>: lock decl (%rax)
0x00007ffffe79086b <__libc_start_main+299>: sete   %dl
0x00007ffffe79086e <__libc_start_main+302>: test   %dl,%dl
0x00007ffffe790870 <__libc_start_main+304>: je     0x7ffffe790892 <__libc_start_main+338>
0x00007ffffe790872 <__libc_start_main+306>: xor    %eax,%eax
0x00007ffffe790874 <__libc_start_main+308>: jmp    0x7ffffe790830 <__libc_start_main+240>
0x00007ffffe790876 <__libc_start_main+310>: mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
0x00007ffffe79087b <__libc_start_main+315>: lea    0x16bdb3(%rip),%rdi        # 0x7ffffe8fc635
0x00007ffffe790882 <__libc_start_main+322>: mov    (%rax),%rsi
0x00007ffffe790885 <__libc_start_main+325>: xor    %eax,%eax
0x00007ffffe790887 <__libc_start_main+327>: callq  *0x118(%rdx)
0x00007ffffe79088d <__libc_start_main+333>: jmpq   0x7ffffe7907a5 <__libc_start_main+101>
0x00007ffffe790892 <__libc_start_main+338>: mov    $0x3c,%edx
0x00007ffffe790897 <__libc_start_main+343>: nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
0x00007ffffe7908a0 <__libc_start_main+352>: xor    %edi,%edi
0x00007ffffe7908a2 <__libc_start_main+354>: mov    %edx,%eax
0x00007ffffe7908a4 <__libc_start_main+356>: syscall 
0x00007ffffe7908a6 <__libc_start_main+358>: jmp    0x7ffffe7908a0 <__libc_start_main+352>
0x00007ffffe7908a8 <__libc_start_main+360>: mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
0x00007ffffe7908ad <__libc_start_main+365>: mov    0x3a35bc(%rip),%rdx        # 0x7ffffeb33e70
0x00007ffffe7908b4 <__libc_start_main+372>: lea    0x16bd94(%rip),%rdi        # 0x7ffffe8fc64f
0x00007ffffe7908bb <__libc_start_main+379>: mov    (%rax),%rsi
0x00007ffffe7908be <__libc_start_main+382>: xor    %eax,%eax
0x00007ffffe7908c0 <__libc_start_main+384>: callq  *0x118(%rdx)
0x00007ffffe7908c6 <__libc_start_main+390>: jmpq   0x7ffffe7907de <__libc_start_main+158>
0x00007ffffe7908cb <__libc_start_main+395>: mov    0x168(%rax),%r13
0x00007ffffe7908d2 <__libc_start_main+402>: mov    0x3a3527(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ffffeb33e00
0x00007ffffe7908d9 <__libc_start_main+409>: xor    %r12d,%r12d
0x00007ffffe7908dc <__libc_start_main+412>: mov    (%rax),%rbp
0x00007ffffe7908df <__libc_start_main+415>: mov    0x18(%r13),%rax
0x00007ffffe7908e3 <__libc_start_main+419>: test   %rax,%rax
0x00007ffffe7908e6 <__libc_start_main+422>: je     0x7ffffe7908f8 <__libc_start_main+440>
0x00007ffffe7908e8 <__libc_start_main+424>: mov    %r12d,%edi
0x00007ffffe7908eb <__libc_start_main+427>: add    $0x47,%rdi
0x00007ffffe7908ef <__libc_start_main+431>: shl    $0x4,%rdi
0x00007ffffe7908f3 <__libc_start_main+435>: add    %rbp,%rdi
0x00007ffffe7908f6 <__libc_start_main+438>: callq  *%rax
0x00007ffffe7908f8 <__libc_start_main+440>: add    $0x1,%r12d
0x00007ffffe7908fc <__libc_start_main+444>: mov    0x40(%r13),%r13
0x00007ffffe790900 <__libc_start_main+448>: cmp    %r12d,%r14d
0x00007ffffe790903 <__libc_start_main+451>: jne    0x7ffffe7908df <__libc_start_main+415>
0x00007ffffe790905 <__libc_start_main+453>: jmpq   0x7ffffe7907d6 <__libc_start_main+150>
```

---

And then eventually the assembler code of `__GI_exit` (again, whose code is not seen in the objdump of the program):

```
0x00007ffffe7aa030 <__GI_exit+0>:  lea    0x38a5c1(%rip),%rsi        # 0x7ffffeb345f8 <__exit_funcs>
0x00007ffffe7aa037 <__GI_exit+7>:  sub    $0x8,%rsp
0x00007ffffe7aa03b <__GI_exit+11>: mov    $0x1,%edx
0x00007ffffe7aa040 <__GI_exit+16>: callq  0x7ffffe7a9f10 <__run_exit_handlers>
```

---

And then a few more, and so on, until the program exits.

---

So, my question is, how can I view this extra assembler code when `objdump`ing my dynamically linked executable?

I tried statically compiling it as well (the file was massive when I `objdump`ed it), and there wasn't a 1-to-1 relationship in the dynamically linked code of the dynamically linked executable and the (formerly) dynamically linked code of the statically linked executable.

I'm assuming there are some optimizations going on that contort the (formerly) dynamically linked code in the statically linked executable for the better.

But my mission is to `objdump` the dynamically linked code in the dynamically linked executable; not to `objdump` the (formerly) dynamically linked code in the statically linked executable.

Comment: Am I using the terminology in its proper context? Or which is preferred among the three: assembler code, functions, or sections?

Comment: Simply run objdump on the relevant dynamic libraries.  There are probably elegant ways to find what you want, but the forward text search in most pagers will do it, too.  Some of the code ultimately involved would live in the dynamic linker itself.  Of course it might be more useful to track down the source for all of these, in most cases it is published.

Comment: @ChrisStratton
"...forward text search in most pagers..."
What is a forward text search in a pager?
"Some of the code ultimately involved would live in the dynamic linker itself." Code can live in the dynamic linker?
"Of course it might be more useful to track down the source for all of these, in most cases it is published."
How would I track down the sources for this assembler code? And published where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of dynamic linking a library is not including the library in the object, so the sections you want to disassemble just aren't there.
You could even replace the dynamic library (the .so object) with something else, which could result in different code being run by your same main program.

So you first need to identify which dynamic objects are referenced by your program. For this, you can used `ldd`. Example:

```
$ cat x.c
int main(void) {
}
$ cc -o x x.c
$ ldd x
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff553e8000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff12b0fa000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff12b6ed000)
$
```

Now you can `objdump` the files referenced here. Note you won't find the vdso anywhere; it resides in the kernel and is automatically provided for every program that runs. See `man 7 vdso` for more information.

To see the source code, just google for glibc source; you'll find the source of the C library itself (`libc.so.6`) and the dynamic loader (`ld-linux-x86-64`) there.